# Sum between a range of dates from two different worksheets

Tags: excel, date, worksheet

I have two worksheets, let's name it Apple and Banana. I want to see the answers in Apple and get the values from Banana with the criteria January 1 - 15, 2016 only.

Given:

- A2:A3000 with the dates
- E2:E3000 the amount or expenses

My formula is:

```
=SUMIFS('Banana'!E2:E3000,'Banana'!A2:A3000,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),'Banana'!E2:E3000,"<"&DATE(2016,1,15))
```

It is adding the amount, but the problem is, it is also adding amounts greater than and equal to January 16.

Also, do you think it has something to do with the formatting of my dates in Banana? It is formatted as `mm,dd,yy`. But, if I put `&Date`, it requires `year,month,day`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument 5 should be should be Banana!A2:A3000 (i.e. same as Argument 2) not Banana!E2:E3000 as you have it, because it must be the date column (A) not the value column (E).

Comment: Yeah!! The problem is with my eyes! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`=SUMIFS(Banana!E2:E3000,Banana!A2:A3000,">="&DATE(2016,1,1),Banana!A2:A3000,"<"&DATE(2016,1,15))`

The correct arguments you should pass into a `SUMIFS` are:

Syntax:

**SUMIFS(sum_range, criteria_range1, criteria1, [criteria_range2, criteria2], ...)**

For full details [see here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b)

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. I now see the problem. :)